# I want inflate two xml in the same listview

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I want to put this design in mi xml. At first one header and one picture once, and then many row to show information about the photo. My problem is that when I put all in a RelativeLayout when I select the first row I select the photo, header and first row. Therefore I have to put in two xml the main element (Photo and header) and in other xml all the rows. How can I inflate in Listview two xml? I don't know how I can do this.

I can't post images therefore the structure will be:

(One item in listview)
1) HEADER and PHOTO don't repeat
2) ROWS - more than one row

It is like to put a header into one row of listview. Because I want to put comments in each photo and could be more than one per each photo.

I had all in the same xml but with this format I had the problem when click on one row.

The photo and user details only must be shown once and rows depends on each photo, there are photos with more than one rows. Therefore I think the best option will be to do two xml files and inflate it from java code, but I don't know to do this. If someone have another best option will be accepted.

And my getView code is the following:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder;

        Object repeat = MyArrList.get(position).get("Repeat");

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);

            //Userdetails
            holder.tvU = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvU);
            holder.tvUN = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvUN);
            holder.ivProfilePhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profilephoto);

            //Accessory details
            holder.tvN = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvN);
            holder.tvB = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvB);
            holder.tvP = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvP);
            holder.tvS = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvS);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }
        else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        holder.imageView.setRotation(90);

        if(repeat.equals("1")){

            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.tvU.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tvUN.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tvU.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("U").toString());
            holder.tvUN.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("UN").toString());

        }
        else {
            //If the photo_id is repeated these params are not shown
            holder.tvU.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tvUN.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

        try {
            Bitmap bmp = ((Bitmap) MyArrList.get(position).get("ImageThumBitmap"));

            Bitmap photobitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width/2, height/2, true);
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) MyArrList.get(position).get("Photo"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // When Error
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_report_image);
        }

        holder.tvN.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.tvN.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("N").toString());

        holder.tvB.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.tvBsetText(MyArrList.get(position).get("B").toString());

        holder.tvP.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);

        holder.tvP.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("P").toString());

        holder.tvS.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
        holder.tvS.setText(MyArrList.get(position).get("S").toString());

        return convertView;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

better you can put the Header in a separate Xml and add this into your ListView Header as follow

```
init listView
inflate header and add it to the list
set any adapter to listView (!!!)
set listView adapter
```

Comment: A practical example is always better than just writing the steps.

Comment: I don't understand totally, you said to put in three different xml (one for header, other for image and other for rows)? In this way I be able to touch the items separately but I don't know how implement this.

Comment: you don't wanna do like this you can create two XML one for Header and Image and other for rows you can add the first xml as the header to the list view and other for list view adapter you can refer the following link to add the header in the list view http://blograchita.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/listview-with-header-footer-view-android/ if you have any other queries regarding this please let me know

Comment: I think I have not explained well. I want a header for each block and each block contains Header, image and some rows. The header contains the user that uploaded the photo therefore I need to put in in each photo. Each photo can have more than one row.